Siebel - Copy text from screen to Pick/pop-up

Many years ago, when we moved on Open UI, we have customized text area on Siebel to show as a pop-up dialog box (as for High Interactive) instead of Open UI text area
For this functionality we have customized Siebel vanilla file (core-siebel.js and jqgridrenderer.js)
With this set-up when we open application in IE (or Edge with IE mode), when the pop-up was open, we could copy text from any applet and paste into the pop-up(text box)
Moving to Edge/Chrome the copy/paste is not possible, the text (Transaction number/Ids/status/contact etc.) cannot be SELECTED, until we close this pop-up.

The Oracle support replies to us that these kind of changes is not supported, but it's needed to manage this:

If there is a way to restore on Edge/Chrome the behavior of IE (copy/paste)
If changing the customization (moving for example on manifest) if possible to reach the same behavior of IE on Chrome/Edge  in this case it’s needed some doc to customize core file (core-siebel.js and jqgridrenderer.js) using manifest

We have tried using Java-Business Service, a UI baed on Java code to be invoked from the code. But UI based JAR doesn't load using JBS.
We have also tried to discover some options around, .NET based UI, but ActivX is not supported after moving from HI to OpenUI, especially in Chrome.
